# JSON parsing and listing data in PhoneGap not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, phonegap

I'm working on making an API call in PhoneGap. I wrote a function and calling it from a button click event, and I'm getting a response too, but I want to know how to display it. I have tried, but it's not working.

```
function getContactList() {
  console.log("Entering getContactList()");
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      debugger;
      alert(xhr.statusText);
      alert(thrownError);
    },
    success: function(json) {
      console.log("====CONTACTLIST ---->", json);

      $(json).find("contacts").each(function() {
        var html = '<li>' + $(this).find("name").text() +
          ' ' + $(this).find("name").text() + '</li>';
        $('#contacts').append(html);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Do you want to parse a json or xml? Because of `dataType:"json"` `$(xml).find("contact")`

Comment: Wait let me post latest code please

Comment: @Blauharley-Please check my code edit.

Comment: Ok, then assuming that all contacts are located at root-level of this json-file, then you have to iterate over each contact in such way: `json.contacts.forEach(...` or `for(var index=0; index < json.contacts.length; index++){...`

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving JSON string which is then automatically converted by jQuery to a JavaScript object, so you can interact with it directly and shouldn't convert it to a jQuery object like `$(json)`. Change the code inside your `success` to this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.contacts.length; i++) {
  var c = json.contacts[i];
  var html = '<li>' + c.name + ' ' + c.email + '</li>';
  $('#contacts').append(html);
}
```

Note: it seems that there is an error in your code, you're using the `find("name")` twice. I changed it to name & email, but you can use any property of the contacts that you're getting.